# How to fix "The least populated class in y has only one member" Scikit learn

Tags: python, csv, machine-learning, scikit-learn, train-test-split

I am creating a program using past datasets to predict an employees salary for any job. I recieve the error "Warning: The least populated class in y has only 1 members, which is too few. The minimum number of members in any class cannot be less than n_splits=5."

```
p_train, p_test, t_train, t_test = train_test_split(predictors, target target, test_size=0.25, random_state=1)
model = KNeighborsClassifier()
param_grid = {'n_neighbors': np.arange(1, 25)}
modelGSCV = GridSearchCV(model, param_grid, cv=5)
```

Here is where I tried splitting and received the error. I am pretty new to Machine Learning so would appreciate if anyone could guide me on how to fix this.

Comment: Is the `target target` parameter a typo?

Comment: yes, my bad. The actual code does not have this.

Answer (score 1):

From the [GridSearchCV](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html) documentation:

> For integer/None inputs, if the estimator is a classifier and y is
>   either binary or multiclass, StratifiedKFold is used. In all other
>   cases, KFold is used.

You must have a multiclass classification problem.  Since [StratifiedKFold](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold.html) is used, you need to have at least 5 examples of each class in your data.  If you have at least one class with < 5 examples, this error will be thrown.

A simple solution would be to drop classes with < 5 examples or to reduce the number of folds.

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: Are you using pandas?  Assuming yes, as a starting point, you could group by the class column and count how many rows there are for each class.  For example:
df["CLASS_COUNT"] = df.groupby("TARGET_COL").transform("count").  Then filter your DataFrame where "CLASS_COUNT" >= 5.